# Ошибка в коде "if x in p:" вызывает typeerror: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input("Введите значение a:"))
b = int(input("Введите значение b:"))
x = (input("Введите значение x:"))


for p in range(a, b):
    if x in p:
        print(x/a+b)
else:
    try:
        x/a+b
    except:
        print("Error")
    finally:
        print()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Папка", line 10, in <module>
    if x in p:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: элемент из последовательности чисел - это число, а ты его как последовательность хочешь использовать

Comment: скорее всего тут должен был быть оператор сравнения: `==`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, и вы действительно в этом коде проверяете, входит ли x в интервал a...b , то пользоваться перебором - довольно плохое решение. Для целых чисел он будет работать, но при этом будет выполнять кучу лишней работы (особенно на больших интервалах). И алгоритм нельзя будет расширить на дробные числа, если такое понадобится. Правильным решением здесь будет проверить, что x>a и x<b.

Answer (score 2):

В строке `if x in p:` Вы пытаетесь проверить, входит ли `x` в `p`, при этом `p` это не последовательность, а простое число. Для проверки необходимо использовать сравнение:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

a = int(input("Введите значение a: "))
b = int(input("Введите значение b: "))
x = int(input("Введите значение x: "))


for p in range(a, b):
    if x == p:
        print(x/a+b)
else:
    try:
        x/a+b
    except:
        print("Error")
    finally:
        print()
```

Рекомендую также вставить пробел после двоеточий, когда идет ввод данных, это общепринятая практика. Также Вы видимо забыли привести к int значение параметра `x`.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ

Comment: Если не сложно, пометьте этот ответ как принятый (у Вас должна быть доступна для нажатия галочка под стрелкаки вверх и вниз слева от текста моего ответа). Это общепринятая практика на stackoverflow в случае, если ответ Вам подошел.

Comment: @Doper вы можете использовать: `x in range(a, b)` или `a <= x < b` вместо цикла.

Comment: Пожалуйста не копируйте код из вопроса, демонстрирующий плохие практики, не упоминая этого явно: 1- не используйте  bare `except:` (это ловит даже KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit) лучше ZeroDivisionError явно использовать 2- for/else синтаксис здесь совсем не нужен

Comment: Согласен, что код не лучший, но я не ставил целью полностью оптимизировать код, а сосредоточился только на ответе :-) Что касается for/else - возможно, часть кода просто вырезана для упрощения, и в полном варианте этот код таки имеет значение. Однако, в том виде, в каком приведен - согласен, if/else здесь лишние.